# RegEx match till two character match

Tags: php, regex

I am making own template engine parser for custom syntax.

Want to replace some code.

I want to replace `{{ $code }}` by `<?php $code ?>`

Below are test cases for replace code

```
<p>{{ $data . '{data}' }}</p>
   <p>{{ 'data' }}</p>
<p>{{'data'}}</p>
<p>{{  'data'}}</p>
<p>{{'data' }}</p>
    <p>{{
        'data' }}</p>
```

Below is regex which match all cases except first one

```
{{([^}]*)}}
```

Below is url where I added same code

#### http://regexr.com/3c0tn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with `DOTALL` flag:

```
'/{{(.*?)}}/s'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL9xD7/1)

Switch `/s` will make DOT match newlines as well.

Comment: Quick question. Is there any way to possible without '/s'?

Comment: Yes it is possible use: `/{{([\s\S]*?)}}/`

Comment: Great advice as usual, +1 :)